# Selenium Webdriver / Ruby : assert times out

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this line which is hitting a drop down menu and asserting that a list option is present.   If the list item is not present I would like to output the text " list item not present" but instead, it just ends up waiting for ever and eventually timing out entirely.

```
    assert{ displayed?(:xpath, "//li[text() = 'Clinical Review Feedback Type']") }
```

Thanks for the help.

I think maybe i've got it:

```
    begin
        @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[text() = 'Clinical Review Feedback Type']").click  
    rescue => e
        p e.message 
        puts "Filter not found in list"
    end
```

Comment: does the drop down guts are loaded by ajax?

Comment: Yes, it is ajax.  I don't have any issue working with the drop down. It's just that we use the same template for multiple situations and for some situations the list selection is present and some it's not. I just want an easy way to say - hey if this filter isn't in the list that's cool end the test and move on to the next one.

Comment: if elements present, than you set the wrong path; try another way to write path. for example - maybe spaces before and after '=' must not exist?

Comment: This works just fine so I believe it is not the wrong path.
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[text() = 'Clinical Review Feedback Type']").click

Comment: obviously another element contains that text. maybe span inside li. show me your html structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now - thanks everyone for pointing me in the right direction.

```
begin
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[text() = 'Clinical Review Feedback Type']").click  
rescue => e
    p e.message 
    puts "Filter not found in list"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print "list item not present", then you should apply exception handling in your code. In this way if your element not present then catch block print the message in console